# How to test Net::HTTP::Post request in ruby and minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm trying to make sure a callback json object is properly sent by `Net::HTTP::Post`, how do I test it in minitest? What I wanted is to compare the `POST` body to the JSON object that I want to be sent when I call the `#perform` method of a delayed_job class. I also want to make sure a target URL actually received this `POST` request.

I looked at fakeweb, but it looks like it doesn't do `POST` requests. The closest I could do seems to be http://requestb.in/, but it seems to be a bit manual.

Comment: The URL http://requestb.in/ is broken. Perhaps best to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Found [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock), and it's what I wanted.

Comment: I'm unable to make Webmock work in Minitest. Can you post an example?

Comment: Let me know if you found any example for this Minitest Net Http Rails test cases